# Django Settings, Git and Amazon AWS

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Django, Git and Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.

With my Django, I don't want to store my settings files on my git. The problem is now I can't use eb deploy since it copies my git code to my AWS without the settings file and then fails.

How do I tell it keep the previous settings module? Or should I be storing my settings on git? That seems pretty insecure.. Any thoughts about how this should be handled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, storing your settings files with variables in it is not a good way to handle it.

The most obvious way to store the sensitive settings is to use ENV variables and use the [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to read the local ENV variable from your settings.

So keep you settings file on git, but remove all of your sensitive variables from it. And set theses variables dynamically using the `os.environ`. Below is the shortcut method I use to read a `setting` variable from the `ENV`:

```
import os

def get_env_variable(var_name, **kwargs):
    """
    Try to get the settings in the current os environment using the given name.
    Raise if the name is not found, except if the 'default' key is given in
    kwargs (using kwargs allows to pass a default to None, which is different as not passing any default):
    >>> get_env_variable('foo') # raise if `foo` not defined
    >>> get_env_variable('foo', default='bar') # will return 'bar' if `foo` is not defined
    >>> get_env_variable('foo', default=None) # will return `None` if `foo` is not defined
    """
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        if 'default' in kwargs:
            return kwargs['default']
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "Please set the '%s' environment variable." % var_name
        )
```

You can use it like this in your settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '<engine>',
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_env_variable('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': get_env_variable('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PORT')
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have any sensitive informations stored in your settings file. And you can keep it in your git. I don't know Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm sure there is a simple way to set ENV variables.

Comment: That works. Is it considered safe to store credentials in ENV variables? I guess it's as safe as anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `local_settings.py` file and put your secret information into that, then add that file to your `.gitignore` file.

`settings.py` can then import what it needs from your `local_settings.py`.

It isn't the most secure way to do it, but it does keep the information out of your git repo.

Comment: Yeah, I basically do that already. And it is out of my git repository. The problem is that now when I try to deploy to AWS, it doesn't upload my settings so the deploy fails.